# How to create dynamic UITableView cells using iPhone SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview

In my app, I have `UITableView` in which first cell & last three cell's contents are fixed. But in between those cell's contents are different as per array count & content.

**E.g:** ***1st cell+ array count + last three cells***.

The array count different all times.
How can make the table view as I explaining above.

Comment: Have you try some thing ? Then show us...

Comment: No, i don't know what to do.

Comment: in numberofrowsinsection method return as ([array count] + 6). and in the cellForRowAtIndex: check indexPath.row is less than 3 or greater than [arrayCount - 1] and write a logic for separate indexpath row values to show what u want..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add subviews to last three cells then you can use following condition

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cellIdentifier";
 UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

 if (cell==nil) {
  cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
 }

 if (indexPath.row==0) 
  cell.textLabel.text=@"First Cell";
 else if (indexPath.row>[myArray count])
 {
  int k=([indexPath row]-[myArray count]-1);

  switch (k) {
   case 0:
    [cell.contentView addSubview:thirdLastView];
    break;
   case 1:
    [cell.contentView addSubview:secondLastView];
    break;
   case 2:
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lastView];
    break;
  }
    cell.textLabel.text=[lastFixedArray objectAtIndex:k];
 }
 else
  cell.textLabel.text=[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];

 return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply once again!!

Answer (score 3):

//Working code for 1st cell+[dynamic array]+last three Fixed cells

```
  #import "tableTOViewController.h"

@interface tableTOViewController ()

@end

@implementation tableTOViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 myArray=[[NSArray alloc] init];
 myArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Aman",@"Atul",@"Karan",@"Yen",@"Chan",@"Lee", nil];

 lastFixedArray=[[NSArray alloc] init];
 lastFixedArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Snakes",@"Food",@"Drink", nil];

    tblView.delegate=self;
    tblView.dataSource=self;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 return [myArray count]+4;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cellIdentifier";
 UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

 if (cell==nil) {
  cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
 }

 if (indexPath.row==0) 
  cell.textLabel.text=@"First Cell";
 else if (indexPath.row>[myArray count])
  cell.textLabel.text=[lastFixedArray objectAtIndex:([indexPath row]-[myArray count]-1)];
 else
  cell.textLabel.text=[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];

 return cell;
}


@end
```

Comment: +1 for the code. and why dont you try else-if condition instead of if-else inside the else statement.

Comment: recently, my xcode is quitting every time there is a problem,so I am not able to check every condition but you can run and edit as if condition false.@R.A

Comment: I said to just change the code in the above answer..Anyway it still will work. So no problem

Comment: Is this code not working @user1673099? If working then accept it.

Comment: great!! your code is working!! But i need some modification like i also want to identified last three cell separately. Like Last cell for drink,second last for food,third last for snakes. But these three last cell always come in table view.. Help me!!

Comment: great!! But i want to set condition for last three cell to display cell content via subviews. So, how can i put condition for last three cell.. Till Now your code is Great.. Thanks for reply!!

Comment: You want to insert subviews in last 3 cells

Comment: yes, i just want to try finding index of last three cell.  I find solution like: else if (indexPath.row>[myArray count])
    {  if (indexPath.row==myArray.count+1) {
            cell.textLabel.text=@"Third Last";
        }
        if (indexPath.row==myArray.count+2) {
            cell.textLabel.text=@"Second Last";
        }
        if (indexPath.row==myArray.count+3) {
            cell.textLabel.text=@"final Last";
        }
 
        
    }

Comment: I have added new answer for this type of condition you are asking.You can do your work in switch condition I have applied.

Answer (score 1):

In your `numberOfRows` method, return value as

```
4 + [array count];
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` do a switch on `indexPath.row` and accordingly fill your cell contents.